# Unable to chdir() on Git/Cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin

I installed Git via Cygwin on Windows Server. It works out very well. However there's a small issue that when I clone a repo use the command as following:

```
$git clone git@myserver:project.git
```

I always get the following error:

```
fatal: '/project.git': unable to chdir or not a git archive
```

but if I typed in the full path then it works

```
$git clone git@myserver:/home/git/repositories/project.git
```

Did anyone here face this problem before?

Regards,
TL

Answer (score 2):

By default, `git clone` uses SSH as the transfer protocol. When connecting over SSH, you have to specify the full path to the repository -- you cannot use a relative path like `project.git`.

If the machine storing the repos instead uses `git daemon` to serve the repos, and you connect via the Git protocol, then you can specify base path for the repos using the `--base-path=path` flag for `git daemon`.